# Движение объекта по параболе

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, математика

Здравствуйте! У меня плохо с математикой, поэтому я прошу вашей помощи. Как сделать движение объекта от точки до точки, при этом, чтобы он двигался по параболе?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Одно из решений выглядит так:

```
var dist1 = dot2.y - dot1.y,
    dist2 = dot2.y - player.y,
    percent = dist2 / dist1;

percent = percent > 0.5 ? 1 - percent : percent;
player.x = player.constX - (100 * percent);
```

Что здесь происходит: dist1 - это весь путь, dist2 - сколько осталось до второй точки, percent - какой процент пути прошел персонаж. Мы сдвигаем персонажа влево на некоторый процент умноженный на 100. Нам нужно чтобы персонаж вышел и зашел, поэтому мы проверяем: если плеер прошел 50% пути, мы начинаем уменьшать проценты. Поэтому максимальный выступ персонажа влево будет 50, т.к. 100 * 0.5 = 50. Как-то так. Ваши предложения?

Comment: Через 2 точки может проходить бесконечное количество разных парабол. Какая именно из них Вас интересует?

Comment: @Yaant Представьте, что оранжевые точки, это точки пересечения параболы с абсциссой, а прямая по которой движется кубик это и есть парабола.

Comment: @Reaget, небольшой пример того, что имел ввиду Yaant: [графики парабол проходящие через две одинаковые точки](http://umath.ru/calc/graph/?&func=x%5E2-4;-x%5E2+4;x%5E2/2-2;-x%5E2/2+2;%20x%5E2/4-1;-x%5E2/4+1;)

Comment: @Grundy спасибо :) Теперь я понял, что он имел в виду.

Comment: @Reaget, теперь стоит уточнить вопрос: по какой именно параболе это все должно двигаться

Comment: @Grundy а это вовсе и не важно знать по какой параболе, тут важно то что для параболы точки должны быть равноудалены относительно некоторой точки называемой вершиной параболы. получить точки можно построить с помощью кривой безье (см мой ответ), либо применив общий вид уравнения параболы

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно применить квадратичное уравнение кривой безье, так как парабола - вообще говоря, это частный случай кривой второго порядка, которой также является в частности и кривая безье с 3 тремя опорными точками.

Всё что нужно сделать - это определить точку изгиба `p1` которая в случае параболы должна быть равноудалёна от начальной и конечной точек `p0, p2`.

Для генерации точек движения необходимо применить уравнение кривой Безье.

[пример в jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yj2soj6b/14/):

```js
var cnv = document.getElementById("cnv");
var ctx = cnv.getContext("2d");
var path = [], id = 0, speed = 1;

var point = {
  x: 0, y: 0,
  draw: function() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, 10, 0, 2*Math.PI, true);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
};

function getCurvePath(x0, y0, x1, y1, xdepth, ydepth) {
  var p0 = {x: x0, y: y0}, 
      p2 = {x: x1, y: y1},
      p1 = {x: xdepth + (p0.x + p2.x) * 0.5, y: ydepth + (p0.y + p2.y) * 0.5},
      x, y, t = 0, path = [];
  
  for (; t <= 1; t += 0.01) {
  
    x = (1 - t)*(1 - t)*p0.x + 2*t*(1 - t)*p1.x + t*t*p2.x;
    y = (1 - t)*(1 - t)*p0.y + 2*t*(1 - t)*p1.y + t*t*p2.y;
    
    path.push({x: x, y: y});
  }
  return path;
}

function drawCurve(path) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  for (var i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
    ctx.lineTo(path[i].x, path[i].y);
  }
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();  
}

path = getCurvePath(250, 350, 250, 20, 450, 0);
var i = 0;

function render() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cnv.width, cnv.height);
  
  drawCurve(path);
  
  if (i < path.length)
    point.x = path[i].x, point.y = path[i].y;
  else {
    i = 0;
  }
  
  i += speed;
  
  point.draw();
  id = requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

render();
```

```html
<canvas id="cnv" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
```

Собственно, меняя точки `p0, p1, p2` можно получить любую параболу директриса которой параллельна одной из осям, но
стоит обратить внимание на параметры `xdepth` и `ydepth` один из них которых обязательно должен равнятья нулю, иначе парабола не получится